R GAMLSS : How to fit a log-logistic distribution (truncated)?
I'm trying to fit a log-logistic distribution (truncated) with GAMLSS and can't find how to do it.
In the documentation, it says that for Generalized Beta 2 (GB2) :
Setting ν = 1 and τ = 1 in (15.20) gives the log logistic distribution.
To fit the truncated distribution of log-normal, I simply do :
gamlss(data~1, family=trun(par=c(Lower,Upper),family="LOGNO",type="both")))

I found that the family "logLO" exists and works but there's no documentation on it and I can't understand the parametrization.

Is it possible to define a new family based on GB2 family by fixing the two parameters ν = 1 and τ = 1 ?

Other ideas ?


Thank you for your help
Franck

In the past, I've emailed them directly and they were really friendly and helpful. It's been a while since I've used it, but I'll take a look myself as well

Thank you for the idea, I just contacted them.

They didn't respond to me. Does anyone have an idea ?

Sorry to hear that. To help you, we need a minimal reproducible example. Please share your code (a simplified version if your code is long and complex) and your data (or fake data if you can't share the real data). In R, the easiest way to share data is dput(df) where df is replaced with whatever your dataframe is called. (If the data is online, you can also simply share the code to pull the data from the source)
